Socket stuck receiving image
I'm trying to send an image from my raspberry pi and receive it on my MacBook. Then I want to classify it on my MacBook and send that classification back to the raspberry pi. I'm having issues with my socket for sending the image. First, it would get stuck receiving and not know when to move to the next step. Now that I've switched from writing directly to a file to a filestream it's not finding the image. Can you help me?
Server/Macbook:
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

loaded_model = pickle.load(open("best_classifier_model.pkl", 'rb'))

host = "my ip address"
port = 5000


def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.setblocking(1)
    print("Socket created")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind complete")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) #Allows 1 connection
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn
     
try:  
    s = setupServer()
    while True:
        try:
            conn = setupConnection()
            while True:
                print("I'm starting")
               
                #file = open(os.path.join(image_path, image_name), "wb")
                file_stream = io.BytesIO()
                data = conn.recv(4096)
                
                print("Data?")
                while data:
                    file_stream.write(data)
                    data = conn.recv(4096)

                print("Image downloaded")
                
                img1 = Image.open(file_stream)
                img1.save("cerv.jpg", format="JPEG")
                img2= rgb2gray(img1)
                img3 = downscale_local_mean(img2, (10, 10))
                img4 = np.array(img3)
                img=unsharp_mask(img4, radius=20, amount=1)
                
                lx, ly=img.shape
                X=np.zeros((1, lx*ly))
                X=np.reshape(img, (1,lx*ly))
                dilation = loaded_model.predict(X)
                dil=str(dilation[0])
                conn.send(str.encode(dil))
                print(dil, " cm")
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            s.close()
            break
        
    s.close()
    #run in terminal with 
    #python3 "/Users/sandy/Documents/School/Spring 2024/Senior Design/Socket_Mac.py"

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Server shutting down")
    s.close()


Client/Raspberry pi:

try:
        #Establish connection with server
        host = "192.168.50.252"
        port = 5000
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        s.connect((host, port))

        def my_function(s):
                #Once per minute do this
                now= datetime.now()
                current_time=now.strftime("%H_%M_%S")
                fname=f"image_{current_time}.jpg"
                image_path="/home/Documents/Data"
                #Take picture to send to computer here
                file = open(os.path.join(image_path, fname), "rb")
                image_data = file.read(4096)

                #Send picture
                while image_data:
                        s.send(image_data)
                        image_data=file.read(4096)

                file.close()
                print("File sent")

                #Recieve dilation from computer
                data=s.recv(4096)
                dilation=data.decode("utf-8")

                #Write message (include exceptions here)
                message=dilation + " cm"

                #s.close()
                #Write message on the screen

                # Display on screen here

        def run_function(s):
                thread = threading.Timer(60.0, run_function(s))
                thread.start()
                my_function(s)

        run_function(s)

except:
        print("Something went wrong.")
        i2c = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)
        disp = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, i2c)
        disp.fill(0)
        disp.show()
        s.close()


Here's the error I'm getting: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10a653d80>

Not finding the image should generate an error. Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Generally: Just catching all or many exceptions and then just printing the error message may suppress important information. At least call traceback.print_exc() in the except-block.

@MichaelButscher, sorry here is that error:
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x159aaba60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sandy/Documents/School/Spring 2024/Senior Design/Socket_Mac.py", line 63, in 
img1 = Image.open(file_stream)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/sandy/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3280, in open
raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)

Your server is calling Image.open() on a stream that is currently positioned at the end, which means that no data can be read from it.  You need to do .seek(0) to rewind to the beginning.

I'm wondering how the code can reach the Image.open at all. This would normally mean that the connection was closed. Maybe using a message based approach like websockets would be better.

while data: assumes the socket is closed after receiving the image, the only way the while will be false. Also recv(4096) is a maximum received, it could be less. Instead send the size of the image and check the amount received and keep receiving until exactly the bytes expected are received. socket.makefile can help. There are lots of existing answers of this type.

Your client could call socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) when it has finished sending the file. This will result in the while data: loop on the server side getting a null without closing the socket, and still allow the same socket to be used to return a result. (I.e. This results in one direction of the socket being "closed", but not the other.) Another thing to watch out for: you generally want to use sendall; if you do send(some_large_byte_string), there's no guarantee all of the data is sent.
